# Unity | Sprits imported with different color

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, png, game-development

I started trying Unity and I'm facing to something strange, I created some simple spirits using Krita, for example this one which is in yellow color ( #fff407 ):
[image]

This is how it get exported as a png file and how it displayed in Mac which is exactly the same ( #fff407 ):

[image]

However when I import the same png to Unity, it change the color to something totally different which is a really gray yellow ( it become this #7a7947 ).

[image]

Now, I searched and some of the info I find was around the texture compression, and I change the settings as well, using none or high quality, ... none of them make any difference.

Here is also a screenshot from the texture settings:

[image]

it would be great if you can point me to the right direction. Cheers.